# Has anyone made image based languages?

Tags: conlang-creation, writing-systems

This is my first visit here. I have been writing machine/computer languages for about 8 years now. I am completely self taught and use my own tools. I have many languages that I have completed that work wonderfully.

I have a program that I use with each language that translates in real time. Everything works nicely. My languages are around 56k words each. I use a combination of Excel and various custom tools to generate the languages.Language creation is not a easy process, but it is fun.It takes me about 4 hours to create one from scratch. I believe what I am creating is more like machine languages? I am certainly not knowledgeable about how to properly create languages as most on here. Its just a fun obsession.

Lately I have been into creating image languages. Languages based on images. I was curious if anyone has ever made a image language? How did you do it? Did you create your own custom font to go along with your language? Did you program a translation tool or app? What have you experimented with?

This is kinda the package I build with my languages. I even experimented with a meme language. A silly language using 500 of the most popular internet memes in .jpg format. With a tool to translate to and from English. It would be cool if others are doing stuff like this.

Comment: Related questions: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/944/how-to-describe-a-purely-symbolic-writing-system and https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/781/are-there-any-unspeakable-languages/782 and https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/774/organizing-a-lexicon-in-a-logographic-writing-system

Answer (score 7):

This is only an answer to the first part of the question

> I was curious if anyone has ever made a image language?

Yes, there are such languages. They are called **pasigraphy** or **logographic writing system**, and the most successful among them is [Bliss symbolics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blissymbols) (also known as **Semantography**) by Charles K. Bliss.

I am not aware of automated translation tools or other tools helping in creating pasigraphies.

Answer (score 4):

There is a esoteric programming language (neither a conlang, nor a mainstream programming language) called [Piet](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Piet), whose source code is in the form of pixel art. Maybe it can inspire you.

If you can accept emoji as sort-of images standing for names, maybe adding conventional images (or other Unicode characters) to serve as verbs, adjectives, and adverbs, can work.